# giving warning prompt when user wants to delete a specific file in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to make a basic bash script that keeps an eye on a specific file and if I decide to delete this file a warning should come up to confirm the delete. The script should accept one parameter ( the file that is going to be checked on delete) How can I achieve this? I don't understand how I can check if the users actually tried to delete the file when the script is running.

Any tips would be really appreciated

Comment: Not possible in the general case. There are really crazy convoluted approaches you could try to take (ie. a loopback mount via a FUSE filesystem that prompts the user), but they don't make practical sense. What are you *actually* intending to accomplish by this? Could just keeping a hardlinked copy of your file somewhere else, or using `chattr +i` (or other filesystem permissions) to suppress deletion suffice?

Comment: ...if you *control the specific shell* the user is running, you could potentially create a shim around the `rm` command, but that's only of very limited use -- they try to delete the file any other way (through a file manager, through their editor, through a noninteractive shell that didn't source dotfiles that introduce the relevant shim code, etc) and they'll be successful.

Comment: Maybe it's better to preserve the file or make it undeletable (by a user) via permissions than the script approach?

Comment: I suspect that when this question is broadened to a point of answerability, it may well be a better fit on [unix.se] than StackOverflow as such.

Comment: Well basically It is not another user that is going to delete the file. I am the one to do 'rm filename'. So I would run the script like this : `./deletefunction.sh 'filename` and when I enter `rm 'filename ` a warning should come up. My bad for saying another user should get this warning

Comment: Any and every case? Does it need to handle `rm -rf` of any parent directory to where the file is at, for example?

Comment: And in that case you'd need to handle not just the directory name itself, but all possible variants -- cases where it's a symlink target, etc.

Comment: If you really want to preserve a file from yourself, consider using `sudo` to move it to a location you don't have write to, and change its ownership likewise.

Comment: No it does not. It should just be a very basic script that checks if I tried to delete the file. If I did try to remove it then I should get a warning.

Comment: That "basic script", as I said, will be effectively useless, providing a false sense of security but very little actual value.

Comment: Make a script that keeps track of whether a given file exists and give a
warning (and closes) when that file has to be deleted. this is the assignment giving by my teacher about this.

Comment: It'd be interesting to look at the details of that assignment, *exactly* as it was given. Has your professor taught you anything about IPC mechanisms? Named pipes? It's hard to see how they could expect you to implement a multi-process solution (that prompts *before* allowing the deletion) otherwise.

Comment: It also might be worth reviewing [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) -- note that we encourage questions that focus on a *specific problem* with your *existing implementation*; that is, not "how do I do assignment X?", but, "when doing assignment X, I wrote code Y, but it gives error Z".

Comment: @Sergio, ...btw, as another aside -- `==` isn't portable inside of `[ ]`, as the only string comparison operator specified in the standard for POSIX `test` is `=`; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html -- bash allows `==`, but relying on that is a source of bugs when one's code is run with dash, ash, or other baseline POSIX shells. If you want to explicitly use bash-only test syntax, that's `[[ ]]`.

Comment: @Dax, ...one thing you *could* implement is a script that creates a backup copy of a file, watches for the original to be deleted, and then prompts the user to ask whether to restore from backup if the deletion does take place. But that's not preventing the deletion, but rather reversing it after-the-fact.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a really bad idea.** This mechanism is trivial to circumvent, either intentionally or accidentally (running `>file` instead of `<file` will delete its contents just as much as `rm file` does -- moreso, rather, as `rm` will leave other hardlinks in place, but `>file` will clear the data associated with the inode, no matter how many links to it there may be). If doing this prevents you from keeping good backups, deploying automated snapshots, or leveraging appropriate file permissions, it's doing much more harm than good.

Note that the whitelist in question is shell-specific -- if you add a file to the whitelist in one shell instance, it won't necessarily be contained there for another. Also note that the implementation is a proof-of-concept; it doesn't catch recursive removes of a parent directory of a file flagged to be preserved.

```
# Put this in your ~/.bashrc

declare -A whitelisted_files

# If our default readlink isn't the GNU one, but we have GNU readlink installed
# as "greadlink", use it.
if command -v greadlink >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  readlink() { greadlink "$@"; }
fi

whitelist_file() {
  local arg
  for arg; do
    whitelisted_files["$(readlink -m -- "$arg")"]=1
  done
}

rm() {
  local arg sigil_seen=0 confirm
  for arg; do
    if (( sigil_seen == 0 )); then
      [[ $arg = -- ]] && { sigil_seen=1; continue; }
      [[ $arg = -* ]] && continue
    fi
    if [[ ${whitelisted_files["$(readlink -m -- "$arg")"]} ]]; then
      read -p "File $arg is whitelisted; really remove?" confirm
      [[ $confirm = [Yy]* ]] || return 1
    fi
  done
  command rm "$@"
}
```

Thereafter:

```
touch preserve_me
whitelist_file preserve_me
rm preserve_me
```

...will provide a prompt:

```
File preserve_me is whitelisted; really remove?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following function to your .bashrc:

```
rem() {
  read -a files <<< $@
  for i in ${files[@]}; do
    if [[ $i == "1.txt" ]]; then
      rm -i $i
    else
      rm $i
    fi
  done
}
```

Here replace `1.txt` with the filename you want confirm for removal. Then alias `rm` to this function:

```
alias rm='rem'
```

If the user runs the command `rm 1.txt 2.txt`, only `2.txt` will be deleted and the following prompt will be displayed: `rm: remove regular empty file '1.txt'?`

**Remark:** As noted in the comments of this answer, the function `rem` does not properly handle file names with spaces, among other problems, so the answer of Charles Duffy is the way to go.

Comment: This matches *every* file with that name in any directory, not just a specific file in a specific directory. It also is going to behave badly with names with spaces, names with globs

Comment: ...and it completely ignores all but the first argument to `rm`, since it looks only at `$1`, not at `$2` and onward.

Comment: This is still buggy with filenames with spaces. I'd suggest actually testing it (and make sure you're using bash, not zsh, to get the full effect).

Comment: Try `set -- "first argument" "second argument" "* third argument *"; read -a files <<<$@; printf '1) %s\n' ${files[@]}; printf '2) %s\n' "${files[@]}"`, and compare the output from the `1)` parts to the output from the `2)` parts -- they're both wrong, but in different ways.

Comment: (To have something that's not wrong at all, the `read -a` would need to be replaced with `files=( "$@" )`, and then you'd need the type-2 mechanism to iterate over the loop... and to fix the quoting in the other expansions).

Comment: (well, *sorta* "not wrong at all" -- all the extra work my answer does to distinguish between the argument `-f` and a file named `-f`, and to track the directory within which any given file is whitelisted, is within the bounds of things you'd need to include to be *completely* correct... and even then, it still doesn't check for recursive deletions from a parent directory, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I much appreciate your help in improving my answer.